# Searching through a dictionary quickly

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store a few hundred strings in a data structure. Every string has two fields associated with it, like say word meaning and its origin.I can store the words in any fashion, say sorted,reverse sorted or anyway you like.

---

I just need to search for a string within the dictionary as quickly as possible and fetch the two related fields. If possible, I want my search to be even better than the binary search.

---

I am using Java. Which `data structure` or `Collection Class` should I use ?

---

Note : I do not want to use database in this.

Comment: You look for exact match or for something like search for `foo` returns the entry for `foobar` as well?

Comment: Well I was looking for the exact same thing. But if the latter can be done, I would like it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`HashMap<String,MyDataObject>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - it will be fastest and simplest to use.

Average seek time is `O(|S|)`, where `|S|` is the string's length.

You can also try and use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), but make sure you want to give the time for it by profiling the `HashMap` solution before you start working on it.

Comment: How do you mean that he should use the `HashSet<String>`? It has a `contains` method but not a `get`. And he says he needs to store key-value pairs.

Comment: @maba: You are correct, I thought he also wants to check for existence, which a Set fits for. From second read - it is definetly not the issue. Editting.

Comment: You should implement to interfaces

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is "use a `HashMap`", but it is not without caveats. Every string you search for will need its hashcode calculated. If you use a new object every time, you pay O(*s*) every time (*s* being string length in this case), plus another O(*s*) for an `equals` check.

One way around this is to `intern` all the strings you use for searching. This will ensure the once-calculated hashcode is reused and will also short-circuit the ensuing `equals` check.

Another option is using a *trie*. Its advantage is that you pay at most O(*s*), but generally less—it is a prefix-based search, so a soon as you traverse up to the point where your prefix is unique, you get the result.

In conclusion, if you can arrange for the reuse of `interned` strings, a hashcode-based solution is optimal; if not, a *trie* is a superior choice.

Other commonplace options would be a skip list (used in Lucene) and B-tree (common in database indexes).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but after a hash match was found - an `equals()` method should still be applied - and unless the stored `String` and the seeked `String` is the *exact same object* it will be `O(|S|)` anyway.

Comment: @amit If the keys are interned, that's exactly what's going to happen -- the exact same object is going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashTable` or `HashMap`

your structure should look something like this `HashMap<String,Bookcontent>`

where `BookContent` is a class with attributes word meaning and origin

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **Trie** data structure. I have done an assignment something similar to this. 
This [link](http://vkroz.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/prefix-table-trie-implementation-in-java/) helps you in implementing Trie DS.